# Seeder Laravel com 2 relacionamentos

Tags: laravel

preciso de uma ajuda, estou querendo criar, para cada **Categoria**, um **Local** e para cada **Local**, uma **Cidade**, porém ao rodar as seeds, ocorre o erro abaixo:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::each()

**Model Place**

```
<?php

namespace Moviet\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'city_id',
    'category_id',
    'name',
    'description'
];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
}
```

**Model Category**

```
<?php

namespace Moviet\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name'
    ];

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }
}
```

**Model City**

```
<?php

namespace Moviet\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function place()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
    }
}
```

**Seeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Moviet\Models\Category;
use Moviet\Models\City;
use Moviet\Models\Place;

class CategoryTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Category::class, 10)->create()->each(function($c) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
                $c->places()->save(factory(Place::class)->create()->each(function($p){
                    $p->cities()->save(factory(City::class)->make());
                }));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Estou usando Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar esse problema, tem que ter em mente a lógica de existir primeiro, no caso, **Cidade** e **Categoria** devem existir para que **Local** possa também existir, ou seja, uma sequencia lógica.

`Seed` ideal:

```
class CategoryTableSeeder extends Seeder
{   
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Category::class, 10)->create()->each(function($c) {

            factory(City::class, 1)->create()->each(function($a) use ($c)
            {
                factory(Place::class, 1)->create([
                    'name' => 'a',
                    'description' => 'a',
                    'city_id' => $a->id,
                    'category_id' => $c->id
                ]);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Ele vai criar 10 registros para todas as tabelas e relacionando as `id` subsequentes e ordenadas.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [db:seed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding)
- [Writing Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#writing-factories)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas o problema continua :(

Comment: Relate o problema ???? @EduardoPaludo esse código foi testado em cima da sua pergunta! Diga pra mim o que está aparecendo no console!

Comment: O mesmo erro citado no inicio do post, usando seu codigo, o problema ocorre da mesma forma.

Comment: @EduardoPaludo o problema está de difícil reprodução como te alertei esse código foi testado e aqui funcionou perfeitamente, igual está na sua pergunta, faz o seguinte comando no console `php artisan cache:clear` e tente novamente o Seed, e se não der certo aponte a linha do erro, cole o erro na sua pergunta por favor

Answer (score 0):

Para ilustrar como trabalhar com *seeders* temos a relação entre as tabelas *company* e *bank* `1-N`:

**Models**
    //Company Model
    public function bank()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bank::class);
    }

```
//Bank Model
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

**ModelFactory**

Obs.: Procure utiliza o arquivo `ModelFactory.php` para criar suas *factory* em um arquivo separado.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\Models\Company::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'uuid' => $faker->uuid,
        'cnpj' => rand(10000000, 99999999) . '0001'
    ];
});
```

Note que na *factory* do *bank* eu não precisei passar a chave estrangeira para o *faker* "setar" uma valor qualquer.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\Models\Bank::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'account' => $faker->randomNumber(6),
        'bank_agency' => $faker->randomNumber(4)
    ];
});
```

**Seeder**

```
//Seeder Company
public function run()
{
    factory(Company::class, 50)->create();
}

//Seeder banck
public function run()
{
    $company = Company::pluck('id');
    factory(Bank::class, 50)->make()
        ->each(function ($bank) use ($company) {
           $bank->company()->associate($company->random(1)->first());
           $bank->save();
        });
}
```